# design pattern for sql builder

Tags: design-patterns

I want to write sql builder ( in: conditions(where, limits, table, etc), out: pure sql. ). Which design pattern nearest for this task?

Comment: There's an existing library (and looks well designed, much better than the kludge I'm forced to use here at work) for this at http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of expression tree along with a visitor or maybe some kind of interpreter.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern